# Как заставить отображать значение 0 в круговой диаграмме на canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Использую [IE8+ Radial Progress Bar](http://codepen.io/vinsongrant/pen/bNJxYG), не могу пофиксить, чтобы при `value="0"`

*сюда не получилось рабочий пример разместить, так что дал ссылку на codepen

Выводил именно 0, не 100. Я так понимаю, что при "null" надо делать проверку при рендере, но не могу понять где.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в функции `myDelay`, у вас не происходит `window.clearInterval(tmr)` при условии `m==val`, так как `m` у вас минимум 5 и проверку со значением `val=0` оно просто не проходит, по этому крутит к 100.

Проблема будет не только при 0, так как у вас шаг +5, то очистка интервала произойдет только когда ваш итератор совпадет со значением (которое в этом случаи должно быть кратное 5).

Чтобы выводился 0 нужно просто `m += 5;` писать после конструкции `if`.

Comment: Это не совсем сработало, но просто постваил 'var m = -5;', не свосем правильно, но работает.

Comment: @Jarvis почему же не сработало, [переносим m+=5 за if](https://jsfiddle.net/7dx363ts/)